# Does kfree fill the memory with 0x6b?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I ran into a bug that I found somehow the memory will be filled with '0x6b' for each char by someone else. (I check the memory via printk, not ICE.) After a lot of debugging I found out that it was because I accidentally did kfree to the memory (it was allocated by kmalloc).

I'm curious about who fills the '0x6b' and trace the kfree code but can't find the code doing this. Is it a debugging mechanism of Linux kernel or there is some other reason?

(the env is kernel 4.9)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a debugging mechanism of Linux kernel ...?

Yes, it's called "slab poisoning".

Here is the `0x6b` declared in the source for memory freeing:

https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/poison.h#L56

And here's a short blurb about it:

https://whatilearned2day.wordpress.com/2006/12/13/slab-poisoning/